# Notice: Undefined index: error in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 13

Tags: php

keep getting this error , can someone explain & help me ..

Notice: Undefined index: error in C:\wamp\www\test\index.php on line 13

the code :

```
<?php
include "inc/config.php";
include "inc/template.php";

head($title);
openbody($title);
?>
<h1>Sistem Maklumat Kekosongan Jawatan</h1>
<h3>JobsMalaysia Center Danga Bay</h3><br />
<br />
<?php
$err = get_error($_GET['error']);
echo '<p>'.$err.'</p>';
?>
<?php   
closebody();
?>
```

Comment: Please show full code? where does the line "$err=get_error($_GET['error']" comes?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_GET` super-global doesn't contain the key `error`, it should be fairly self-explanatory.

You can bypass the error by using:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
    $err = get_error($_GET['error']);
    echo '<p>'.$err.'</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I personally would make it a little more clean by doing something like this: http://ideone.com/b46OhZ

So you can abstract out the isset part a little more. Just a personal preference.

Comment: I don't think that there's any point in extracting that code into a separate function. `isset()` is already sufficient, why would you want to wrap everything in another function call?

Comment: Because A. eventually he's going to want to add more to it and B. you can make it one line of code to use multiple places instead of 3.